# What is this stain I am seeing images taken on my new MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, camera, macbook

I have got a new MacBook Pro. Wwen I use the camera for taking a photo, for Skype, etc. I see a kind of stain in a corner of the image. I attach a photo here. See right down corner over the line of the wall. Any idea why is that?

[image]

I try to clean the camera and here is a photo while a cloth on the cam.

[image]

Comment: Can you see this on the exterior camera,that is, clean the camera lens.   Otherwise, I suggest you return it right away.

Comment: To be so sharply in focus, I'd think it has to be on the sensor itself. If it was on the lens it would be blurred. Send it back.

Comment: Others said it but if this is a new MacBook Pro and it can be shown so easily to others, return it. Not worth the headache — and risk of damage — to clean it up on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The lens is damaged or has a defect as I suggested in my earlier comment.

Return the unit for a new one under warranty. This is a warranty item and the unit can be replaced or possibly repaired if Apple wishes to replace the Camera.